# what is the correct way to add external url in mkdocs

Tags: mkdocs

I tried this but didn't work, it still showing the index page, what is the correct way?

```
nav:
  - Home: index.md
  - 'Document': 'https://www.google.com/'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be automatically inferring that it is an external link, per [the documentation](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#nav):

> Any path which is not found in the files is assumed to be an external link.

Have you tried it without the `www`, adding quotes around the `index.md` (although I'm not sure why that would work), and/or modifying your indents? Those are the only differences I can notice between yours and the example:

```yaml
nav:
    - Introduction: 'index.md'
    - 'about.md'
    - 'Issue Tracker': 'https://example.com/'
```

Comment: how to open in `target="_blank"` ? for me the quotes are unnecessary